# Fabric.js setHeight() and scaleToHeight() gives different height values

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have an issue with image resizing. I want to resize an image but without keeping ratio. When I'm using setHeight() it gives me wrong value.

```
image.setHeight(100);
image.getHeight(); // gives me 140px output
```

When I'm using scale function all is correct, but it keeps image ratio also

```
image.scaleToHeight(100);
image.getHeight(); // correct 100px output
```

Also this test gives me strange values:

```
console.log("h: " + image.getHeight()); // 348.25870646766174
image.set({ height : image.getHeight()-10 });
console.log("h: " + image.getHeight()); // 235.6030791317047
```

EDIT:

More code:

```
var flatImage = document.getElementById("flat-image");

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("frame-canvas",{                         
        width: 992,
        height: 450
});

var image = new fabric.Image(flatImage, {});
    image.selectable = false;
    // image.scaleToWidth( 250 );

canvas.add(image);
canvas.centerObject(image);
canvas.renderAll();

console.log("h: " + image.getHeight()); // 334
image.set({ height : image.getHeight()-10 });
console.log("h: " + image.getHeight()); // 324 works good
```

But when I add scaleToWidth() height values gets strange:

```
image.scaleToWidth( 250 );

console.log("h: " + image.getHeight()); // h: 166.66666666666666
image.set({ height : image.getHeight()-10 });
console.log("h: " + image.getHeight()); // h: 78.17697937458415
```

Basically cut on half and then subtracts given value.

Why is that ?

Comment: It will be good if you can share some more code, because it is working fine as it should be http://jsfiddle.net/xz1n4d6n/

Comment: I put some more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the snippet looks fine. 
I can't think any other reason for getting different values,
just please take a look on the scale properties `img.scaleX` and `img.scaleY` and make sure that they are **equal 1**, otherwise that causes the problem.

good luck

Comment: Yes. It seems that scaleToWidth() changes those properties, so I have to manually change image width to desired value then change image height. Thank you.